# windows server 2003 shared folders not accessible

Tags: windows

I have server 2003 server and it was accessible from other but now all shared folders of this servers are not accessible from others. I have disabled Antivirus firewall, windows firewall but still issue is same.i can ping that server from others by name and IP both. please suggest solution for this issue.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/608881/why-should-i-start-to-replace-windows-server-2003/608882#608882

Answer (score 0):

Since you can ping by hostname/FQDN & IP, we can assume the TCP stack is loaded.

1. Can you access the shares via the loopback address (`\\127.0.0.1\$sharename`) from the host
   server?
2. Have you verified that the share is up? (compmgmt.msc or `net
   share`)
3. Is the Server service running? Try restarting it (notice: will
   disconnect file sessions)

The Server service reads from:
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares`

Verify your shares are there.